# Google Data Studio Region City

Tags: region, looker-studio, city

I'm trying to show the region's cities for the number of new users. It is working, as I'm getting the same data value as shown in Google Analytics. But visually the map image is greyed out (meaning there's no data) and when I hover over the map it doesn't show the name of the cites.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved, please check the image[image]